# If $A\twoheadrightarrow B$ with $B$ a domain, can I find a preimage of a monic irreducible polynomial which is also monic irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Suppose $\phi:A\twoheadrightarrow B$ is a surjective homomorphism of commutative rings with unit, with $B$ an integral domain (note that $A$ is not an integral domain in general). Suppose $g\in B[X]$ is a monic irreducible polynomial. Can I find a preimage of $g$ in $A[X]$ which is also monic irreducible?

Here an element is irreducible means that it is not a unit, and if it is a product of two elements, then one of the elements is a unit.

A related (maybe easier or harder) question: if $b\in B$ is an irreducible element, can I find a preimage of $b$ in $A$ which is also irreducible?

---

Background: we want to prove that if $K/A$ is an integral ring extension with $K$ a field, then for any irreducible polynomial $f\in K[X]$, should there exists a monic irreducible polynomial $g\in A[X]$ such that $f\mid g$ as polynomials in $K$. It turns out that [our proof](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Mathlib/RingTheory/AdjoinRoot.html#Irreducible.exists_dvd_monic_irreducible_of_isIntegral) only works when $A$ is a domain: in this case let $x$ be a root of $f$ in $\overline K$, and let $g$ be the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $A$.

When $A$ is not a domain, let $B$ be the image of $A$ in $K$, then $B$ is a domain and the above proof works for $K/B$. So we can get a monic irreducible polynomial $g\in B[X]$. Now the remaining part is the question I asked here.

---

[EDIT] Combined with current two answers, we know that it's true for irreducible rings, but not for not connected rings. The in-between cases are rings which are connected, but not irreducible, for example $k[u,v]/(uv)$. Can we say anything about such rings?

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity: irreducibility of $g\in A[X]$ means that for any factorization $g=ab$ either $a$ or $b$ is a unit in $A[X]$? This is not equivalent to the non-existence of a factorization $g=ab$ with $\deg(a)>0$ and $\deg(b)>0$ for if $A$ possesses nilpotents, then $A[X]$ possesses units of positive degree.

Comment: @HagenKnaf Yes, your definition of irreducibility is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A step towards an answer (?)

Claim: let $g\in B[X]$ be an irreducible monic polynomial of degree $d>0$ and assume that the nilradical of $A$ is a prime ideal. Then every
monic preimage $G\in A[X]$ of degree $d$ is irreducible.

(1) Let $Q$ be the kernel of $\phi$ and let $N$ be the nilradical of $A$. Then $N\subseteq Q$ and one can factor the homomorphism $\phi$ into

$
A\rightarrow A/N\rightarrow B,
$

where by assumption $A/N$ is a domain. The induced homomorphisms

$
A[X]\rightarrow A/N[X]\rightarrow B[X]
$

are surjective.

Every monic preimage $h\in A/N[X]$ of degree $d$ of $g$ is irreducible, since $A/N$ is a domain. Hence it suffices to prove the claim in the case $\mathrm{kern}(\phi)=N$.

(2) Let $G=PQ$ be a factorization in $A[X]$ of a monic preimage of $g$ of degree $d$. Let $p,q\in B[X]$ be the images of $P$ and $Q$. Then $g=pq$ and since $g$ is irreducible one can assume $p\in B^\times$. Hence $P=a_0+P_{>0}$, $a_0\in A\setminus N$ and $P_{>0}\in N[X]$, where the latter consists of all non-constant monomials of $P$. Let $Q=Q_{>d}+Q_{\leq d}$ be the decomposition of $Q$ into polynomials consisting of monomials of degree $>d$ respectively $\leq d$ only. Then $Q_{>d}\in N[X]$, since $g$ has degree $d$.

Let $a_i$, $b_j$ and $c_k$ be the coefficents of $P$, $Q$ and $PQ$ respectively. Then

$
a_0b_d+a_1b_{d-1}+\ldots +a_db_0=c_d\not\in N,
$

since $g$ has degree $d$. However $a_1,\ldots ,a_d\in N$ yields $a_1b_{d-1}+\ldots +a_db_0\in N$, hence $\phi(a_0)\phi(b_d)=1$ and therefore $a_0b_d=1-n$ for some $n\in N$. By assumption $n$ is nilpotent, which implies that $1-n$ and therefore $a_0$ are units of $A$. Consequently $P$ is a unit in $A[X]$ and the factorization $G=PQ$ is not proper.

Comment: Great! Let me read your proof later. Your condition means that $A$ is irreducible (i.e. it has only one minimal prime ideal), right?

Comment: Argument "the first summand on the right-hand side must be zero" seems incorrect, because $P_{\leq d}Q_{\leq d}$ can also have non-zero monomials of degree $>d$.

Comment: Yes, what a stupid mistake. I hope to be able to replace this false argument ...

Comment: Thank you very much! Now this proof works. Combined with Badam Baplan's answer, we know that it's true for irreducible rings, but not for not connected rings. The in-between cases are rings which are connected, but not irreducible, for example $k[u,v]/(uv)$. Can you say anything about such rings?

Comment: Your argument also works for $k[u,v]/(uv)$, but uses the specified properties of this ring. Let me see if it can be generalized.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is usually going to work without significant restrictions on $A$ (see Hagen Knaf's answer for a possible restriction).

Let $A$ be a ring with a non-trivial idempotent $e$ and $a, b \in A$ such that $a + b := u$ is a unit with inverse $u'$.  Then in $A[x]$, $x + (ea + b)$ is reducible as $((1 - e)x + (ea + b))(u' ex + 1)$.

In particular, if you take any field $k$ and adjoin an idempotent $e$, then the retract $A:= k[e] \twoheadrightarrow B:= k$ gives you a counterexample.  Because in $A[x]$, every monic polynomial projecting onto $x + 1$ will be of the form $x + (ea + b)$ contemplated above, and will thus be reducible.

Comment: Thank you for your counterexample. Let me check it it's also a counterexample for my original question.

Comment: In fact we have this: if $A=A_1\times A_2$, then any monic $f\in A[X]$ of degree $\geq 1$ is NOT irreducible. For if $\phi_i:A\twoheadrightarrow A_i$ then $\phi_i(f)\in A_i[X]$ is also monic of degree $=\deg(f)\geq 1$, which is not a unit. Hence we can find $f_1,f_2\in A[X]$ such that $\phi_i(f_i)=\phi_i(f)$ and $\phi_i(f_j)=1$ if $i\neq j$. Now $f=f_1f_2$ and $f_i$ are not units. This gives counterexample of both of my questions.

Comment: @JzPan Good point, i needlessly complicated things!  So, if $A$ is not connected, then every non-constant monic polynomial of $A$ is reducible.